# Is This MSDTC configuration Issue?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, msdtc

It seems I am running into the Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC) related issue.

**SCENARIO**

I am using TransactionScope and with in the single scope it hits two different databases on different servers (for instance, **DB_A** running Windows Server 2003 and **DB_B** running Windows Server 2008). One database is accessed using Entity Framework 4.0 and another using normal ADO.NET APIs.

When I run the application from my development machine (running WinXP) it commits and rollbacks both the connections accurately. But when I run the application, deployed on another server (for instance **WAS_A** running Windows Server 2003) it commits correctly but in case of exception is doesn't roll back the database activities on both the servers.

I thought it would be the MSDTC configuration issue on the **WAS_A**. So I went to the MSDTC -> Security Configuration and checked all the available options (as I did previously on other machines). But still I am facing the same issue.

Looking for your expert advices. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to look into [Enabling Transaction Flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733116%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Specifically, take a look at how one may error and the other complete as described in [TransactionScope and WCF Services](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/200911/Blog/TransactionScope-and-WCF-Services/):

> an error in a second WCF service call was NOT rolling back the changes made in a previous WCF service call...
>   In order to create an ambient transaction in your client and ensure that it is used by your WCF services...

The article then details the following steps:

- Configure Your Binding with `transactionFlow`
- Decorate Your Interface with `[TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption)]`
- Decorate Your Method with `[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired)]`
- Optionally update your Connection Strings with `Transaction Binding`*

*Note: This is optional in my opinion.